Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
I am developing a web project with spring boot using jpa, I have a problem using swagger and testing an api of mine named getAppointmentById, I tried using @JsonIgnore, @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference but none of them worked.Here are the details:
Swagger not responding
enter image description here
Logs:
2024-07-13T02:31:04.739+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1f15d346, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7fb70e94, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@17c7cc93, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@346d8002, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5abf9a76, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@688884e, org.petspa.petcaresystem.config.JwtRequestFilter@2c9af700, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1b2213b2, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@bf0025d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4e132a9b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@762e3836, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7b237c2c]
2024-07-13T02:31:05.124+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-07-13T02:31:05.133+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [           main] o.p.p.PetcaresystemApplication           : Started PetcaresystemApplication in 5.292 seconds (process running for 5.641)
2024-07-13T02:31:13.356+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-13T02:31:13.356+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-13T02:31:13.358+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Hibernate: select a1_0.appointment_id,a1_0.boarding_appointment_id,a1_0.create_date,a1_0.end_time,a1_0.pet_id,a1_0.review_id,a1_0.start_time,a1_0.status,a1_0.user_order_id from appointment a1_0 where a1_0.appointment_id=?
Hibernate: select ba1_0.boarding_id,a1_0.appointment_id,a1_0.create_date,a1_0.end_time,p1_0.pet_id,p1_0.age,p1_0.gender,p1_0.owner,p1_0.pet_name,p1_0.species,p1_0.status,p1_0.type_of_species,r1_0.review_id,r1_0.user_id,r1_0.description,r1_0.rating,r1_0.status,a1_0.start_time,a1_0.status,uo1_0.user_order_id,uo1_0.user_id,uo1_0.price,uo1_0.order_date,ba1_0.boarding_time,s1_0.shelter_id,s1_0.shelter_name,s1_0.shelter_status,s1_0.status,ba1_0.status from boarding_appointment ba1_0 left join appointment a1_0 on ba1_0.boarding_id=a1_0.boarding_appointment_id left join pet p1_0 on p1_0.pet_id=a1_0.pet_id left join review r1_0 on r1_0.review_id=a1_0.review_id left join user_order uo1_0 on uo1_0.user_order_id=a1_0.user_order_id left join shelter s1_0 on s1_0.shelter_id=ba1_0.shelter_id where ba1_0.boarding_id=?
Hibernate: select au1_0.user_id,au1_0.address,au1_0.age,au1_0.create_date,au1_0.email,au1_0.full_name,au1_0.gender,au1_0.password,au1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,au1_0.status,au1_0.user_name from authen_user au1_0 left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=au1_0.role_id where au1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select bd1_0.appointment_id,bd1_1.doctor_id,d1_0.department_id,d1_0.address,d1_0.department_name,d1_0.status,s1_0.schedule_id,s1_0.date,s1_0.status,bd1_1.user_id,u1_0.user_id,u1_0.address,u1_0.age,u1_0.create_date,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.password,u1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,u1_0.status,u1_0.user_name from doctor_booked bd1_0 join doctor bd1_1 on bd1_1.doctor_id=bd1_0.doctor_id left join department d1_0 on d1_0.department_id=bd1_1.department_id left join schedule s1_0 on s1_0.schedule_id=bd1_1.schedule_id left join authen_user u1_0 on u1_0.user_id=bd1_1.user_id left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=u1_0.role_id where bd1_0.appointment_id=?
Hibernate: select bs1_0.service_id,bs1_1.service_id,bs1_1.description,bs1_1.discount_percent,bs1_1.price,bs1_1.service_name,bs1_1.status from service_booked bs1_0 join services bs1_1 on bs1_1.service_id=bs1_0.appointment_id where bs1_0.service_id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.pet_id,p1_0.age,p1_0.gender,p1_0.owner,p1_0.pet_name,p1_0.species,p1_0.status,p1_0.type_of_species from pet p1_0 where p1_0.pet_id=?
Hibernate: select uo1_0.user_order_id,uo1_0.user_id,uo1_0.price,uo1_0.order_date from user_order uo1_0 where uo1_0.user_order_id=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.review_id,r1_0.user_id,r1_0.description,r1_0.rating,r1_0.status from review r1_0 where r1_0.review_id=?
Hibernate: select ba1_0.boarding_id,ba1_0.boarding_time,ba1_0.shelter_id,ba1_0.status from boarding_appointment ba1_0 where ba1_0.boarding_id=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.department_id,d1_0.doctor_id,s1_0.schedule_id,s1_0.date,s1_0.status,d1_0.user_id,u1_0.user_id,u1_0.address,u1_0.age,u1_0.create_date,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.password,u1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,u1_0.status,u1_0.user_name from doctor d1_0 left join schedule s1_0 on s1_0.schedule_id=d1_0.schedule_id left join authen_user u1_0 on u1_0.user_id=d1_0.user_id left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=u1_0.role_id where d1_0.department_id=?
2024-07-13T02:31:13.636+07:00  WARN 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Ignoring exception, response committed already: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
2024-07-13T02:31:13.637+07:00  WARN 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)]
2024-07-13T02:31:21.573+07:00  INFO 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [io-8080-exec-10] o.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource  : Init duration for springdoc-openapi is: 898 ms
Hibernate: select a1_0.appointment_id,a1_0.boarding_appointment_id,a1_0.create_date,a1_0.end_time,a1_0.pet_id,a1_0.review_id,a1_0.start_time,a1_0.status,a1_0.user_order_id from appointment a1_0 where a1_0.appointment_id=?
Hibernate: select ba1_0.boarding_id,a1_0.appointment_id,a1_0.create_date,a1_0.end_time,p1_0.pet_id,p1_0.age,p1_0.gender,p1_0.owner,p1_0.pet_name,p1_0.species,p1_0.status,p1_0.type_of_species,r1_0.review_id,r1_0.user_id,r1_0.description,r1_0.rating,r1_0.status,a1_0.start_time,a1_0.status,uo1_0.user_order_id,uo1_0.user_id,uo1_0.price,uo1_0.order_date,ba1_0.boarding_time,s1_0.shelter_id,s1_0.shelter_name,s1_0.shelter_status,s1_0.status,ba1_0.status from boarding_appointment ba1_0 left join appointment a1_0 on ba1_0.boarding_id=a1_0.boarding_appointment_id left join pet p1_0 on p1_0.pet_id=a1_0.pet_id left join review r1_0 on r1_0.review_id=a1_0.review_id left join user_order uo1_0 on uo1_0.user_order_id=a1_0.user_order_id left join shelter s1_0 on s1_0.shelter_id=ba1_0.shelter_id where ba1_0.boarding_id=?
Hibernate: select au1_0.user_id,au1_0.address,au1_0.age,au1_0.create_date,au1_0.email,au1_0.full_name,au1_0.gender,au1_0.password,au1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,au1_0.status,au1_0.user_name from authen_user au1_0 left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=au1_0.role_id where au1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select bd1_0.appointment_id,bd1_1.doctor_id,d1_0.department_id,d1_0.address,d1_0.department_name,d1_0.status,s1_0.schedule_id,s1_0.date,s1_0.status,bd1_1.user_id,u1_0.user_id,u1_0.address,u1_0.age,u1_0.create_date,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.password,u1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,u1_0.status,u1_0.user_name from doctor_booked bd1_0 join doctor bd1_1 on bd1_1.doctor_id=bd1_0.doctor_id left join department d1_0 on d1_0.department_id=bd1_1.department_id left join schedule s1_0 on s1_0.schedule_id=bd1_1.schedule_id left join authen_user u1_0 on u1_0.user_id=bd1_1.user_id left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=u1_0.role_id where bd1_0.appointment_id=?
Hibernate: select bs1_0.service_id,bs1_1.service_id,bs1_1.description,bs1_1.discount_percent,bs1_1.price,bs1_1.service_name,bs1_1.status from service_booked bs1_0 join services bs1_1 on bs1_1.service_id=bs1_0.appointment_id where bs1_0.service_id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.pet_id,p1_0.age,p1_0.gender,p1_0.owner,p1_0.pet_name,p1_0.species,p1_0.status,p1_0.type_of_species from pet p1_0 where p1_0.pet_id=?
Hibernate: select uo1_0.user_order_id,uo1_0.user_id,uo1_0.price,uo1_0.order_date from user_order uo1_0 where uo1_0.user_order_id=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.review_id,r1_0.user_id,r1_0.description,r1_0.rating,r1_0.status from review r1_0 where r1_0.review_id=?
Hibernate: select ba1_0.boarding_id,ba1_0.boarding_time,ba1_0.shelter_id,ba1_0.status from boarding_appointment ba1_0 where ba1_0.boarding_id=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.department_id,d1_0.doctor_id,s1_0.schedule_id,s1_0.date,s1_0.status,d1_0.user_id,u1_0.user_id,u1_0.address,u1_0.age,u1_0.create_date,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.password,u1_0.phone,r1_0.role_id,r1_0.role_name,r1_0.status,u1_0.status,u1_0.user_name from doctor d1_0 left join schedule s1_0 on s1_0.schedule_id=d1_0.schedule_id left join authen_user u1_0 on u1_0.user_id=d1_0.user_id left join role r1_0 on r1_0.role_id=u1_0.role_id where d1_0.department_id=?
2024-07-13T02:31:34.408+07:00  WARN 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Ignoring exception, response committed already: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
2024-07-13T02:31:34.408+07:00  WARN 2080 --- [petcaresystem] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)]


Appointment.java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Appointment")
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "appointment_id")
    private Long appointmentId;

    @ManyToMany
//    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
            name = "doctor_booked",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id"))
    private Collection<Doctor> bookedDoctor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Pet pet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private LocalDate create_date;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    @Column(name = "startTime", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    @Column(name = "endTime", nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    @ManyToMany
//    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
            name = "service_booked",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"))
    private Collection<Services> bookedService;

    @OneToOne
    // @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "userOrder_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
    private UserOrder userOrder;


    // @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "boardingAppointment_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
    private BoardingAppointment boardingAppointment;

    // @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id", nullable = true)
//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Review review;
}


Doctor.java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Doctor")
public class Doctor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "doctor_id")
    private Long doctorId;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private AuthenUser user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Departments department;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookedDoctor")
    @JsonIgnore
//    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<Appointment> appointment;


//    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id", nullable = true)
    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Schedule schedule;
}

Services.java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Services")
public class Services {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "service_id")
    private Long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "service_name", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "type_service", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "serviceType_id"))
    private Collection<ServiceType> typeOfService;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "discount_percent", nullable = true)
    private int discountPercent;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private Status status;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookedService")
    @JsonIgnore
//    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<Appointment> appointment;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "services")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Combo> serviceCombo;
}

Controller
@GetMapping("/getAppointment/{appointmentId}")
   @CrossOrigin
   public AppointmentResponseDTO getAppointmentById(@PathVariable Long appointmentId) {
      AppointmentResponseDTO appointmentResponseDTO = appointmentService.findAppointmentById(appointmentId);
       return appointmentResponseDTO;
   }

Service
public AppointmentResponseDTO findAppointmentById(Long appointmentId) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format_pattern);
        String timeStamp = localDateTime.format(formatter);
        String message = "Create new appointment successfully";
        int statusCode = HttpStatus.OK.value();
        HttpStatus statusValue = HttpStatus.OK;


        AppointmentResponseInfor infor = new AppointmentResponseInfor();
        AppointmentResponseData data = new AppointmentResponseData();
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment();


        try{
            appointment = appointmentRepository.findByAppointmentId(appointmentId);
            if(appointment == null){
                message = "Appointment not found!";
                statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value();
                statusValue = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
                infor.setMessage(message);
                infor.setStatusCode(statusCode);
                infor.setStatusValue(statusValue);
                return new AppointmentResponseDTO(infor, data);
            }

            // status
            data.setStatus(appointment.getStatus());

            // create date
            data.setCreate_date(appointment.getCreate_date());

            // start time
            data.setStartTime(appointment.getStartTime());

            // end time
            data.setEndTime(appointment.getEndTime());

            // find booked doctor
            Collection<Doctor> bookedDoctors = appointment.getBookedDoctor();
            List<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<>(bookedDoctors);
            for (Doctor doctor : doctorList) {
                data.setBookedDoctor(doctor);
            }

            // find booked service
            Collection<Services> bookedServices = appointment.getBookedService();
            List<Services> serviceList = new ArrayList<>(bookedServices);
            for (Services service : serviceList) {
                data.setBookedService(service);
            }

            // find pet
            Pet pet = petRepository.findByPetId(appointment.getPet().getPetId());
            data.setPet(pet);

            // user order
            UserOrder userOrder = ordersRepository.findByUserOrderId(appointment.getUserOrder().getUserOrderId());
            data.setUserOrder(userOrder);

            // review
            Review review = reviewRepository.findByReviewId(appointment.getReview().getReviewId());
            data.setReview(review);

            // boarding appointment
            BoardingAppointment boardingAppointment = boardingRepository.findByBoardingId(appointment.getBoardingAppointment().getBoardingId());
            data.setBoardingAppointment(boardingAppointment);

        }catch (Exception e){
            message = "Something went wrong, server error!";
            statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
            statusValue = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            infor.setMessage(message);
            infor.setStatusCode(statusCode);
            infor.setStatusValue(statusValue);
        }

        infor.setTimeStamp(timeStamp);

        return new AppointmentResponseDTO(infor, data);
    }

AppointmentResponseData.
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppointmentResponseData {
    private Long appointmentId;
    private Status status;
    private LocalDate create_date;
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
    private Doctor bookedDoctor;
    private Services bookedService;
    private Pet pet;
    private UserOrder userOrder;
    private Review review;
    private BoardingAppointment boardingAppointment;
}

AppointmentResponseInfor.java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppointmentResponseInfor {
    private String message;
    private String timeStamp;
    private int statusCode;
    private HttpStatus statusValue;
}

AppointmentResponseDTO.java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppointmentResponseDTO {
    private AppointmentResponseInfor responseInfor;
    private AppointmentResponseData data;
}

I tried using @JsonIgnore, @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference but the result is still the same.

please show stacktrace of the error

I meant show it to us, by adding the complete error log (also known as stacktrace) to the question

I've added stacktrace above at logs part

I also tried adding e.printStackTrace() and logger.error("Error", e) in the catch section, but it didn't print anything else, I tried debugging and realized the program didn't throw any exception and ran fine until returning the response, it seems the error is in the response returning part I think. I added the relevant classes above.
